# PhpStorm disable hints after typing, enable method parameter hints

Tags: phpstorm, type-hinting, phpstorm-2016.1

It's driving my crazy that every time I type a comma and than hit enter, some hinted method is inserted into my code because PhpStorm thought it should display a code hint. I only want hinting when I'm typing a variable or a method name, is this possible?

Also, I once saw some PhpStorm hinting that when the user typed a method name, PhpStorm displayed the required variables just above that method as a hint, but I can't find the setting for it.

I don't mean this, but I can't find an image of it:
[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2016.3/py_viewParameterInfo.png]

Comment: 1) All available settings for Code Completion popup are located at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion` 2) *"every time I type a comma and than hit enter"* Show you settings perhaps -- I personally do not have such behaviour -- I see no code completion popup after typing comma. 3) `View | Parameter Info` to bring it up manually; works inside brackets only; shown automatically when writing function/method call for a first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just found out it was probably some beta version of [PhpStorm 2017.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/), I downloaded the release today and instantly saw what I was looking for:

[image: PhpStorm 2017.1]